# Graylog2 - Startup fail. Address already in use

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2

I am trying to install graylog2. I have installed open-jdk7. I have also installed elasticsearch and mongodb using apt on ubuntu 14.04.

I am new to both graylog and elasticsearch. I just want to try a trail installation and try these out. And I also did search similar questions and tried their suggestions. But none of them worked for my case.

I have followed the installation instructions on [graylog.org](https://www.graylog.org/documentation/setup/server/). But when I try to start the graylog2 server I get the following error.

```
2015-02-12 03:19:36,216 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.IndexerClusterCheckerThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [30s].
2015-02-12 03:19:36,222 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.GarbageCollectionWarningThread] periodical, running forever.
2015-02-12 03:19:36,225 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.IndexerClusterCheckerThread - Indexer not fully initialized yet. Skipping periodic cluster check.
2015-02-12 03:19:36,229 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.ThroughputCounterManagerThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [1s].
2015-02-12 03:19:36,280 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.DeadLetterThread] periodical, running forever.
2015-02-12 03:19:36,295 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.ClusterHealthCheckThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [20s].
2015-02-12 03:19:36,299 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.InputCacheWorkerThread] periodical, running forever.
2015-02-12 03:19:36,334 DEBUG: org.graylog2.periodical.ClusterHealthCheckThread - No input running in cluster!
2015-02-12 03:19:36,368 DEBUG: org.graylog2.caches.DiskJournalCache - Committing output-cache (entries 0)
2015-02-12 03:19:36,383 DEBUG: org.graylog2.caches.DiskJournalCache - Committing input-cache (entries 0)
2015-02-12 03:19:36,885 ERROR: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager - Service IndexerSetupService [FAILED] has failed in the STARTING state.
org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9300]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:396)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.start(InternalNode.java:242)
        at org.graylog2.initializers.IndexerSetupService.startUp(IndexerSetupService.java:101)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$2$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:54)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:95)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:9300
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport$3.onPortNumber(NettyTransport.java:387)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.transport.PortsRange.iterate(PortsRange.java:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:383)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:372)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        ... 1 more
```

Elastic search is showing the following status

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "graylog2",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

The following are the changes I made to elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: graylog2
network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1
network.host: 127.0.0.1
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", MYSYS IP]
```

and graylog2.conf

```
is_master = true
password_secret = changed
root_password_sha2 = changed
elasticsearch_max_docs_per_index = 20000000
elasticsearch_shards = 1
elasticsearch_replicas = 0
elasticsearch_cluster_name = graylog2
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_multicast_enabled = false
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = IP_ARR:9300
mongodb_useauth = false
```

I tried killing the process on the port 9300 and tried starting graylog again. But I got the following error

```
2015-02-12 04:01:24,976 INFO : org.elasticsearch.transport - [graylog2-server] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]}
2015-02-12 04:01:25,227 INFO : org.elasticsearch.discovery - [graylog2-server] graylog2/LGkZJDz1SoeENKj6Rr0e8w
2015-02-12 04:01:25,252 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.service - [graylog2-server] processing [update local node]: execute
2015-02-12 04:01:25,253 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.service - [graylog2-server] cluster state updated, version [0], source [update local node]
2015-02-12 04:01:25,259 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.service - [graylog2-server] set local cluster state to version 0
2015-02-12 04:01:25,259 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.service - [graylog2-server] processing [update local node]: done applying updated cluster_state (version: 0)
2015-02-12 04:01:25,325 WARN : org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [graylog2-server] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x82f30fa7]], closing connection
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:127)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:644)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)

    .......

2015-02-12 04:01:28,536 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.health - [graylog2-server] no known master node, scheduling a retry
2015-02-12 04:01:28,564 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [graylog2-server] disconnected from [[graylog2-server][LGkZJDz1SoeENKj6Rr0e8w][ubuntu-greylog-9945][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]]{client=true, data=false, master=false}]
2015-02-12 04:01:28,573 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen - [graylog2-server] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
2015-02-12 04:01:28,590 WARN : org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [graylog2-server] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xe27feaff]], closing connection
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:127)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:644)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)
```

Can you please point out to what I am doing wrong here and what I am missing??

Answer (score 1):

if ES and greylog2 running on same server, try (del/comment) in elasticsearch.conf

```
#transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

and (add/uncomment) in greylog.conf

```
elasticsearch_transport_tcp_port = 9350
```